# Why I can't build jar in Maven

Tags: java, maven, javafx, javafx-8, maven-3

Already I checked all the advice about similar problems. Nothing works. Maybe someone has an idea of what the problem is? Below pom file and console with an error.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>pezal2</groupId>
  <artifactId>pezal2</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <properties>
 <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>  
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>8.5.0</version> 
        <configuration>
        <mainClass>com.pezal.Main</mainClass>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    </plugins> 
  </build>
</project>
```

Console

```
   [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.zenjava:javafx-maven-plugin:8.5.0:jar (default-cli) on project pezal2: Execution default-cli of goal com.zenjava:javafx-maven-plugin:8.5.0:jar failed: Plugin com.zenjava:javafx-maven-plugin:8.5.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact javafx-packager:javafx-packager:jar:1.8.0_20 at specified path C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_101/../lib/ant-javafx.jar -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

Comment: Looks like you upgraded from java 1.8.0_20 to 1.8.0_101; try `mvn -U`

Comment: `[ERROR] No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify,`

Comment: Can you say something more about this?

Comment: @Bartek - What Maven goal(s) did you try to run?

Comment: I did everything like it is here in the video [LINK](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wbjW8rYlook)

Comment: When I'm at the place of entry 'jfx:jar' occurs an error included in the question

Comment: Please add some more details to your question, like the Maven goals you tried to run

Comment: When I prepared, and all directories and files were in any place I used Maven install, and then Maven Build (jfx:jar). And the building is such an error.  Maybe it's java versions 1.8.0_101. It is an option that JavaFX and Maven does not work in this version? I may add that even in a project I'm using SQLite but still her pom file did not include

Comment: Running `mvn dependency:resolve -X` give us more specific details

Comment: Hi, I'm the maintainer of the javafx-maven-plugin. You are required to have the JDK installed, on windows you might have to set JAVA_HOME pointing to the JDK, not the JRE.

Comment: I have an indication of the JDK and does not work. It may be something about "1.8.0_20 to 1.8.0_101"  but what to do to change it? Uninstall and reinstall the eclipse and java? Help anything? More data will give for about 5 hours

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your JAVA_HOME links to JRE, not JDK. Try

```
mvn package -Djava.home="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101"
```

Comment: Tested, and such and such an appeal. Nothing that does not change

Comment: I think you gathered full resolution for your question. The `javafx-maven-plugin` needs access to ant-javafx.jar, which is located through ${java.home} variable (see https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin/blob/javafx-maven-plugin-8.5.0/pom.xml). You must correctly setup your environment