# Re-build the project JavaFX Maven based project JavaFx without Maven - Eclipse

Tags: java, maven, javafx, javafx-8

I made a project in JavaFX in eclipse. I had to reinstall the system which led to the removal of Java and Eclipse. I project files I had saved. I installed everything again, and decided to create a new project based on the files of the previous using the Maven (Java-JavaFX-Maven). And there is a lot of errors.

Eg.

How should the appeal in this case?

I have a

```
MainView.fxml
application.css
MainViewController.java and a few filse with class in *.java
```

.

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MainView.fxml"));
scene.getStylesheets().add("application.css");
```

Where should be located xml and css files and what appeal set?

catalogs:

```
src/main/java/com.pezal
src/main/resources
```

In the `MainView.fxml` have set a reference to the controller `com.pezal.MainViewController`

Throws an exception:

I can not find references

Also I can not build a jar using Maven

The question already asked before but no one has answered the question. I thought maybe it was some internal error and reinstall help.
[Why I can't build jar in Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39735173/why-i-cant-build-jar-in-maven)

If someone can look at this link and help I'd be very grateful.

Comment: Does this mean you don't want to use Maven?

Comment: Maybe you want to use the javafx-maven-plugin for JavaFX-development, some example using ProGuard and controller-references can be found here: https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin/tree/master/src/it/08-build-with-proguard

Comment: Please make sure to have Eclipse configured to use the JDK, not just the JRE: http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2011/11/15/Telling-Eclipse-to-use-the-JDK-instead-of-JRE.aspx

Comment: I want. I need to build an application running in Windows Because the person for whom I do it will not be installed the Java and also the way I learn how it can be done. Just learning Java because the only way I can do it.

Comment: please make sure Eclipse is using the JDK instead the JRE, link posted above (might solve your problem)

Comment: ok, so I will be able to see something later so as to let you know here

Comment: @FibreFoX  Thx, Now, everything works as it should. You can add this as an answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124569/discussion-between-bartek-and-fibrefox).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse needs to be configured to have the JDK used, per default the JRE will get used, which MIGHT WORK to have maven running, but not for compiling.

Some instruction out on the net: http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2011/11/15/Telling-Eclipse-to-use-the-JDK-instead-of-JRE.aspx

For having some example for placing fxml-files and using them inside your code, you might want to checkout some example-project of the javafx-maven-plugin: https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin/tree/master/src/it/08-build-with-proguard

**Disclaimer:** I'm the maintainer of the javafx-maven-plugin